# Perl regex and replacement — substitutions on URL strings

Tags: regex, perl

Hey I have basic questions about Perl.

I have a link like this

```
my $url = "http://test.com/index.php?id=123&test=1&l=1";
```

I have three values. I want to count the `id` up and open it.

The pages are not static. So the base URL may change or the query parameter.

- I need a regex like `(*)?(*)=(*)&(*)` and I want to count up the numbers in each parameter.
- Another problem is that I want to add `a` to the parameter counts like `1a`, `2a`, `3a` etc. and start some requests for each modified parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by 'count up the numbers in each'? Can you give an example? Likewise - "adding an `a`" - what does your new URL look like?

Comment: I think you mean `my $url`...

Answer (score 4):

It's best to use the [`URI`](http://metacpan.org/module/URI) module for manipulating URLs

Here's an example that builds the hash `%query` from the query component of the URL

I don't understand what you mean by *"I want to count the id up and open it."*. The value for the `id` parameter is in `$query{id}`, and is 123, but I can't imagine what *counting it up* might be

I have used `Data::Dump` only to display the contents of the resultant hash. It's not necessary in your production code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;

my $url = URI->new('http://test.com/index.php?id=123&test=1&l=1');
my %query = $url->query_form;

use Data::Dump;
dd \%query;
```

#### output

```
{ id => 123, l => 1, test => 1 }
```

---

#### Update

It sounds like you want to create several new URLs with an `a` added to the value of each query parameter in turn

Here's an example of how that would work

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;

my $url = URI->new('http://test.com/index.php?id=123&test=1&l=1');

for my $param ( $url->query_param ) {
    my $new_url = $url->clone;
    $new_url->query_param($param => $url->query_param($param) . 'a');
    print $new_url, "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
http://test.com/index.php?id=123a&test=1&l=1
http://test.com/index.php?id=123&test=1a&l=1
http://test.com/index.php?id=123&test=1&l=1a
```

Comment: thats it! thats solution one.

Comment: now the other part. thats something new. i want to count each parameter up like i got a ur test.com/inde.xpph?id=2&test=4 i want to split all parameters to string like id=2 and test=4 after that i want ot generate a list of id=1-100 and a list like test=1-100, thats what i need

Comment: @user5293028: That's still a little unclear. Do you want to create all the possible URLs with the `id` and `test` parameters varying from 1 to 100? There are ten thousand different URLs like that. I have given you the tools to do what you need. I suggest you try to take this step yourself, as it's not that hard, and if you get stuck you should post a new question explaining the problem and showing your code

Comment: Note: This assumes that none of the named parameters repeat. That's probably fine.

Comment: no i want to generate a list.txt, the perl script should split the urls parameters in each parameter and count the value up from 1 to 100 and write them to the .txt like id=1\n id=2\n id=3\n and then write append test=1\n test=2\n and so on

Comment: @ikegami, i asked this question as a second part in the first post :P

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $url = "http://test.com/index.php?id=123&test=1&l=1";

my %param = $url =~ m/(\w+)\=(\w+)/g;

print Dumper \%param;
```

If you want to 'add an `a` to all parameters:

```
$url =~ s/(\w+=\w+)/$1a/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

To match all url parameters and capture each parameters name and value as group 1 and 2 of each match:

```
/(?<=[?&])(\w+)=(\w+)/
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/GyfdCXyAyb).

Comment: nice one, how can i now count up each parameter and generate a new link from it ?

Comment: that's a separate question: please ask a new question